# Combining background color and gradient in one background CSS attribute

Tags: html, css

I'd like to combine a solid color and a gradient in a single `background` CSS attribute. Then, I want these two backgrounds to have separate size and position parameters being specified in separate `background-position` and `background-size` attributes in order to put these two backgrounds next to each other.

```css
div {
    width: 400px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid gray;
    
    background: red, linear-gradient(to right, black, white);
    background-position: left, right;
    background-size: 70% 100%, 30% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I expect this to look like this:

[image]

However, Chrome says the background property has an invalid value:

[image]

I fail to understand why.

I tried to find similar answers on Stack Overflow / google but most are about combining a color with an image, which seems to be a different thing since it is treated as a "single background". In my case, I want to have color and gradient to be "two backgrounds" with separate sizes / positions.

**I do not want to incorporate the solid color into the gradient** (which would be possible in this example) because of two reasons:

- In the end, the gradient should be rotated, but the border between the two backgrounds to stay vertical.
- The position / size should be animated in a transition (the 70%/30% ratio should be changed when hovering), which cannot be done with single gradient stops.

My current work-around, which I cannot believe to be really necessary here, is to wrap the solid color in a gradient with the same start and end color. Kind of ugly, and I am sure there is a simpler way...

Comment: Based on the fact that to have to add all the extra CSS using a pseudo, adding the extra gradient seems a much more clever approach ... so I deleted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, Chrome says the background property has an invalid value [...] I fail to understand why.

A color value can only appear in the last layer in an element with layered backgrounds, as stated in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background). You are specifying a color in a layer other than the last, which renders your shorthand declaration invalid.

> My current work-around, which I cannot believe to be really necessary here, is to wrap the solid color in a gradient with the same start and end color. Kind of ugly, and I am sure there is a simpler way...

There isn't. That's the only pure CSS workaround. You could instead opt for a Base64-encoded data URI representing a single red pixel, but either way, you're going to have to specify an image value if that solid color must overlap the gradient.

Comment: Thank you for refering to the relevant section in the spec, which I failed to find. I guess the gradient work-around seems to be the solution to go. I just couldn't believe that ;)

Answer (score 3):

`linear-gradient()` is like `url()`, an image (`background-image`). In the shorthand syntax, color is aside the image (`background-color`) *`<edit>` multiple gradient can be set and animate via `background-size`*:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;   
  background:linear-gradient(to top,red,red) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right,black, white) no-repeat  100% 0 tomato; 
  background-size: 20% auto, 80% auto;
  animation: animate 4s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animate {
from {  background-size: 20% auto, 80% auto;}
30% {  background-size: 10% auto, 10% auto;}
90%, to {  background-size: 70% auto, 30% auto;}
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

---

Note that , red can be included into the gradient instead the use of background-color:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

> The **`linear-gradient()`** CSS function creates a linear, progressive transition between two or more colors. Its result is an object of the `<gradient>` data type, which is a special kind of **`<image>`**.
>
> ```css
> div {
>   width: 400px;
>   height: 200px;
>   border: 1px solid gray; 
>   background: linear-gradient(to right, red 70%,black 70%, white) ;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div>
>
> </div>
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

> The CSS **`background`** shorthand property lets you adjust all of the available background style options at once, including color image, origin and size, repeat method, and other features. `background` can be used to set the values for one or more of: `background-clip`, `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-origin`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, `background-size`, and `background-attachment`.

Comment: Both solutions are a single background. Since I want to animate their size and position, a single gradient will not work. (The bullet points after the bold part of my question is the key problem here.)

Comment: @leemes okay, you want to animate the gradient ? then, first code remains the same, without background-color, but 2 gradients. Use background-position for both, and animate background-size(eventually background-position too if needed). Just use the right syntax to start from ;).

Comment: @leemes first snippet updated with an animation ..... color start/color-stop cannot be animated via css :(

Comment: Well, that updated answer is basically my work-around... ;) But thank you for elaborating on it.

Answer (score 1):

setting a background gradient will be overlayed over the background color.
so if you want only 70% of the screen to be red, you'll need to include it in the gradient as you did.

the reason why your property was not rendered in your js fiddle is because you had a comma separating the different parts of the backround shorthand property. so if you did want for overlay your gradient over the background you need to remove the comma:

```
div {

/* other properties of the div here */

background: red linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 70%, rgb(0,0,0) 70%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0orbjebm/

if you wanted the gradient tinted by the overlay, just add transparency. this is nice if you just want to great to have a gradient that you can overlay with transparency (i altered the sequence just for aesthetic sense

```
div {

  /* other properties of the div here */

  background: red linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 70%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tootz4w8/

in that above example i added a div and added an inline style property for the background color in the div itself and you can see we get nice effects

```
<div>
<!-- this one will be red and fade to black -->
</div>

<div style="background-color:blue">
<!-- this one will be blue and fade to black -->
</div>
```